# How to retrieve column values looping wise in sql?

Tags: sql-server

By filtering data from actual table, I am inserting it into temporary table then some bulk values are coming from it, then again I am inserting it into another temporary table for check loop wise and update some values in actual table into database. So how to retrieve column values looping wise?

Till here i reached:

```
CREATE TABLE #result 
        (           
           PackagePeriod     varchar(20),
           UserId            INT,           
           OldExpiryDate     DATE,         
           AmountToPay       FLOAT,
           PyingAmount       FLOAT,
           Balance           FLOAT,
           LastPaidDate      DATE,
           Company_Id        INT           
        )

create table #temp
        (
            PackagePeriod    varchar(20),
           UserId            INT,           
           OldExpiryDate     DATE,         
           AmountToPay       FLOAT,
           PyingAmount       FLOAT,
           Balance           FLOAT,
           LastPaidDate      DATE,
           Company_Id        INT
        )           

        SET @cmd ='.... where OldExpiryDate<=Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), (GetDate()-1), 106),' ','-')

    select @count=(select COUNT(PackagePeriod) from #temp)

    if(PackagePeriod='Monthly')
    begin
    update ...
    end
    else if(PackagePeriod='Quarterly')
    begin
    update ..
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output. That Stored procedure is a mess.

Comment: As posted this doesn't make much sense. I would like to caution you that it sounds like you are making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Also, you seem to have some datatypes that probably not appropriate for what you are doing. This seems to be a financial application, as such float is generally a poor choice because it is not an exact datatype.

Comment: what is the solution then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I think you can use Cursor or While to solve your problem.

```
CREATE TABLE #result 
        (           
           PackagePeriod     varchar(20),
           UserId            INT,           
           OldExpiryDate     DATE,         
           AmountToPay       FLOAT,
           PyingAmount       FLOAT,
           Balance           FLOAT,
           LastPaidDate      DATE,
           Company_Id        INT           
        )

declare @PackagePeriod     varchar(20)
declare @UserId            int          
declare @OldExpiryDate     DATE         
declare @AmountToPay       FLOAT
declare @PyingAmount       FLOAT
declare @Balance           FLOAT
declare @LastPaidDate      DATE
declare @Company_Id        INT           

declare result_cursor cursor for 
        SELECT PackagePeriod, UserId,  OldExpiryDate,  AmountToPay, PyingAmount, Balance, LastPaidDate, Company_Id from  #result

OPEN result_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @PackagePeriod, @UserId,  @OldExpiryDate,  @AmountToPay, @PyingAmount, @Balance, @LastPaidDate, @Company_Id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    if(@PackagePeriod='Monthly')
    begin
       -- update your table 
    end
    else if(@PackagePeriod='Quarterly')
    begin
        --update table
    end

  FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor INTO @PackagePeriod, @UserId,  @OldExpiryDate,  @AmountToPay, @PyingAmount, @Balance, @LastPaidDate, @Company_Id

END

CLOSE result_cursor

DEALLOCATE result_cursor
```

Comment: Thanq Very much ,understood my exact question and the exact best answer.